# How to make a custom module make available in the defalut content creation area in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, custom-pages

I have a custom module enabled in Drupal 7. Now what I want is, when a user is trying to create content using 'Add content'(be it article/basic page/custom page created by user), I want my module to appear as an option for the user to use it.

How can I possibly do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/node_add_page/7.

It looks like that page is nothing more than a listing of the menu items below node/add. Meaning, you should be able to register a menu path to your create content form below node/add/, e.g. node/add/whatever.